# How do I notify the UITableViewController of events from a UITableViewCell subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a gesture recognizer on each of the table view cells, and when they swipe one I want my delegate to notify the table view (or if there's a better way without delegates, that) so it can be deleted. But how do I know the cell's `indexPath` or whatever so it can be deleted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a delegate is a good pattern to use for this. Your custom cell class should define a protocol and a delegate property. The view controller should set itself as the cell's delegate and the view controller should implement the cell's protocol method(s). Make sure one of the parameters of the protocol methods is the cell.

The view controller can ask the table view for the index path of the cell if that is needed. There is no need for the cell to know its index path. Since rows and sections can be added/deleted, it is bad form for a cell to be told what its index path since it could change at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Have your cell call its delegate with `self` and then in the controller use `UITableView`'s `indexPathForCell:` to find the appropriate index path.

Once you have the path you can use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to remove the cell.  Just remember to make a corresponding change to your data source too!

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates]
[someBackingArray removeObject:someModelObject];

[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[theIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the superView until the class is UITableView.

e.g.

```
id parent = [self superView];
if ([parent isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]) {
   // Got it!
}
```

Note: I'm not sure, but you may have to check one more level "up". i.e. you may need to get the superView of the parent object above until you find the UITableView in the hierarchy.

Comment: How do I then remove the cell?

Comment: You could post a notification to the UITableView using NSNotificationCenter. Or you could use the delegate pattern. Or you could directly call a public method on the UITableView's class.

Comment: But with the delegate, what message would I sent? Just the cell itself and try to find it in the table view (is there like a search method?)?

Comment: You can pass the cell and then use the UITableView's indexPathForCell method to determine that cell's indexPath. Then you can delete the cell at said indexPath using the tableView's deleteCellAtIndexPath method...